# upload file to custom directory in django PYTHON

Tags: python, django, file-upload, error-handling

i have custom form for which i need to upload the image to some directory , below is the code

views function

```
def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid()  and form.is_multipart():
            new_user = save_file(request.FILES['image'])
            return HttpResponse(new_user)
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
        return render_to_response('user_profile.html', { 'form': form })



def save_file(file, path='home/ghrix/ghrixbidding/static/images/'):
    ''' Little helper to save a file
    '''
    filename = file._get_name()
    fd = open('%s/%s' % (MEDIA_ROOT, str(path) + str(filename)), 'wb')
    for chunk in file.chunks():
        fd.write(chunk)
    fd.close()
```

and below is the form:

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="updateform" name="updateform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/user_profile/">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" id="fileinput" name="fileinput" />
    <button class="btn btn-gebo" type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

but am getting this error :

```
The view userprofile.views.user_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says that your view is not returning any `HttpResponse`. There is one case that it's possible -

```
def user_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid()  and form.is_multipart():
            new_user = save_file(request.FILES['image'])
            return HttpResponse(new_user)
# ------^
# There is not else check. It's possible that the if condition is False.
# In that case your view is returning nothing.
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
        return render_to_response('user_profile.html', { 'form': form })
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding that error, the problem is in your view: if your form is invalid, you are not returning a response to the client:

```
def user_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = save_file(request.FILES['image'])
        return HttpResponse(new_user)
else:
    form = ImageForm()

# *** Unindented
return render_to_response('user_profile.html', { 'form': form })
```

also (I don't have much experience with file uploads) but I don't think you need the `is_multipart` check - it may be causing your form to appear invalid.